# Highlight label under finger

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

**Initialization**:

Let's say that I have 5 labels, tagged 1-5. These 5 labels are attached to an `IBOutletCollection` initialized with

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSMutableSet* myLineCollection;
```

**What I want to do:**

When my finger touches and moves across the screen, I want to receive which label my finger is over in `myLineCollection`.

I want to receive this because my end goal is to change the color of the label my finger is currently over from red to blue. But when my finger moves away it should go back to its original color, blue.

I was thinking I should use

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

and / or

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

and / or

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

**I've been trying:**

To use touches, and and if statement for if the touch was in the label.window, or maybe even  c if the touch point is label.frame.length away from label.frame.center.

How can i receive the tag of the current one being touch, and then do something to that tag.
thats all i need

Comment: This isn't a write-my-code-for-me site, and as such people don't react well to phrasing like "Answer in terms of" or "Your answer should."  Tell us what you've tried and how it's not working.

Comment: Phrases like "Your answer should…" are a strong indicator that this question has been lifted from an interview test or an exam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this would helps you:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    //here loops all labels
    for(){
        if (CGRectContainsPoint([lable frame],touchPoint)) {
            //change label's background color
        }
    }
}
```